# How do I initialize and pass an text from a file to a class array for output in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

One of the assignments for my class is to read in a text file with questions, answers and the correct number. I am not sure while my file is not reading correctly, but for some reason I am not getting the information to pass to my class file from the initializing function.

```
void initQuestions(Question q[])
{
    ifstream infile; // Input file to read questions into array     
    infile.open("questions.txt");

    int pos; // loop counter
    string quest; // variable holding question text
    string posAns[numAns]; // variable array holding the possible answers
    int corrAns; // variable holding the correct answer

    // Error message if file unable to open
    if (!infile.good())
    {
        cout << "Error: Unable to open file!" << endl;
    }

    while (infile)
    {
        // Load variables and array from the file using while loop
        getline(infile, quest);
        for (int i = 0; i < numAns; i++)
            getline(infile, posAns[i]);
        infile >> corrAns;

        for (pos = 0; pos < questNum ; pos++)
        {
            q[pos].setQuestionText(quest);
            q[pos].setPossAnswer1(&posAns[0]);
            q[pos].setPossAnswer2(&posAns[1]);
            q[pos].setPossAnswer3(&posAns[2]);
            q[pos].setPossAnswer4(&posAns[3]);
            q[pos].setPossAnswer5(&posAns[4]);
            q[pos].setCorrect(corrAns);

            getline(infile, quest);
            for (int i = 0; i < numAns; i++)
                getline(infile, posAns[i]);
            infile >> corrAns;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my function. The call I am using in main is:

```
initQuestions(&quiz[questNum]);
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Debugger Output:

```
0x00007ffff7b8d44b in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,   
std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::strin
g const&) ()                                                                                                         
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6                                                                     

(gdb) continue                                                                                                       

Continuing.                                                                                                          


Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                          

The program no longer exists.                                                                                        

(gdb)
```

Comment: Debugger.  Use a Debugger.  A Debugger will allow you to execute each statement separately and *watch* values in variables.  Please edit your post with the outcome of your debugging session.

Comment: Why the `pass-by-reference` tag?  You are not passing by reference.  You are calling your function with a pointer to the `questNum` slot in the array.

Comment: I honestly just don't know what my issue is, so I was thinking maybe it was a pass by reference problem. I have added the debugger text if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with how you call the function from your main.

First off when you pass an array you have to just pass the array and its size, secondly an array is passed by reference in c++ so you don't want the `&` so:

Main:

```
initQuestions(quiz , questNum);
```

You method declaration would also have to change:

```
void initQuestions(Question q[], int size)
```

For help with passing an array see:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_passing_arrays_to_functions.htm

Also when reading in a file your should read line by line and check if the line is still good in the while loop.  You are checking if the file itself is good.

There are a lot of questionable things you are doing to read in the file so I highly recommend checking out this resource for examples:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: If you want more clarification on good practices for reading in files I can add the examples to this answer but I would more or less just be rewording the answers from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ with more clarification.

Comment: Rather than using a naked array an appropriate container like `std::vector` or `std::array` should be preferred.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious "assignments for my class" though I agree an std container is better, (memory, efficiency, etc) most classes try to teach students how to use an array.  A lot of fundamentals are based on the array and if a student just uses a std library they won't understand any underlying principles.  As a beginner you should not always take the easy route, you should take the route where you learn the most.  People should really stop suggesting std containers to students.